# Tar xvf working fine, but file not unpacked

Tags: 20.04, tar, unzip

I am trying to download Apache Spark in the folder spark1.

```
$ wget https://downloads.apache.org/spark/spark-3.0.0-preview2/SparkR_3.0.0-preview2.tar.gz
```

Using above statement I get a .gz file. I am trying to unzip this file using below statement:

```
$ tar xvf SparkR_3.0.0-preview2.tar.gz
```

COmmand runs with no error and lot of lines are executed. HOwever when I do `ls` in the folder spark1, there is no unzipped file of SPARK. what to do?

Comment: The unpacked archive should be inside a directory called `SparkR` within the current directory

Comment: You forgot to include the z option for gziped files. ... tar xzvf ...

Comment: pls write this as answer so that others can also benefit

Comment: @ubfan1 that shouldn't be necessary - unless the OP is using something other than GNU tar. See for example [tar extraction also automatically decompresses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253596/tar-extraction-also-automatically-decompresses).

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, but the filename is a clue -- enough said.